# Multicategories

Tags: category-theory

The definition of multicategories is somewhat extensive so I won't give it here, but here's the Wikipedia entry for multicategories: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicategory.

I have two simple questions regarding examples of multicategories.

1. When we construct the multicategory of Sets (let's call it $\mathcal{C}$) we define $\mathcal{C}_{0} = Ob({Set})$, i.e. the objects of the multicategory are sets. And we define $$Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X{n}, X) := Hom_{Set}(X_{1} \times X_{2} \times \ldots \times X_{n}, X)$$

Given $f_{i} \in Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X_{i}^{1}, \ldots, X_{i}^{k_{i}}; X_{i})$ with $i = 1, \ldots, n$ and $g: X_{1} \times X_{2} \ldots \times X_{n} \longrightarrow X$, we'll have a unique function from $X_{1}^{1}, \ldots, X_{n}^{k_{n}}$ to $X$ which yields our composition formula.

Why? I think it's beucase the cartesian product in $Set$ (category of Sets) works like both product and coproduct.

2. How would we define the multicategory of endomorphisms? Just letting the objects being the hom-sets with same domain and codomain?

Thanks.

Comment: The coproduct in **Set** is the disjoint union, not the Cartesian product.

Comment: The composition is just $$(x_1^1,x_1^2,...,x_1^{k_1},x_2^1,...,x_n^{k_n})\mapsto g(f_1(x_1^1,...,x_1^{k_1}),f_2(x_2^1,...,x_2^{k_2}),...,f_n(x_n^1,...,x_n^{k_n}))$$